# Replacing several characters in string with one in C

Tags: c, string, replace, char, c-strings

I need to replace several characters with one (depending if their count is even or odd). If it's even i should replace + with P, if it's odd with p.

Input: kjlz++zux+++

```
while(p[i])
{
    j=i;
    k=i;
    length=strlen(p);

    if(p[i]=='*')
    {
        position=i;
    }
    printf("Position is: %d", position);

    while(p[j]=='*')
    {
        counter++;
        j++;
    }
}
```

Output: kjlzPzuxp

Im not sure how to remove several characters I know how to input one.

Comment: Why are you looking for `'*'`.  You should be looking for `'+'`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can leave the *text* variable intact until you find a +. In that case you start counting how many consecutive plusses there are. Once you know this, it can be decided if you should add a letter P or p. Keep a separate index to write back to your text variable! Otherwise it would start writing to the wrong index after 2 or 3 plusses are found, try to figure out why ;).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    char text[] = "kjlz++zux+++";
    int len = sizeof(text) / sizeof(text[0]);
    int index = 0, count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(text[i] == '+')
        {
            count = 0;
            while(text[i] == '+') i++, count++;
            i--;
            text[index++] = count % 2 ? 'p' : 'P';
        }
        else
        {
            text[index++] = text[i];
        }
    }
    text[index] = 0;
    printf(text);
}
```

You could allocate space for the *text* variable with **malloc** so that you can use **realloc** afterwards to shrink the array to the size of the output text. This way some memory is saved, this is especially important when you start working with bigger chunks of data.

Comment: `text[index++] = count == 2 ? 'P' : 'p';`  should by `text[index++] = count % 2 ? 'p' : 'P';` shouldn't it?

Comment: @Anteino this really helps but i need only text[i] without another variable if it's possible

Comment: And why do we increment output[index++] if i increment i before

Comment: Because at some point *index* is not gonna be equal to *i* and you need to make sure you write to the correct index of *text*. Can you elaborate your previous comment some more?

Comment: @Rexy  This answer modifies the string in place.  To do that you need to have two locations: the source index (which he calls i) and the destination index (which he calls index).  If there are multiple + in a row the two will not be equal - there is no way to do it with one index.

Comment: Problem is also that if I input: kjlz++zux+++

Comment: Output is: kjlzPuxp, z is missing

Comment: Yes, indeed. I fixed that now.

Comment: From a "reasoning about the code" point of view,  I prefer count to be initialized to 0 and the 'P' and 'p' to be swapped in the next line.  Otherwise I wonder "why are we starting at one?"

Comment: And what if i have only one +, it connects me e.g. ab+c, output is abc

Comment: Yes, but when you do that, *i* holds a value that is 1 too high and you'd need to add another line correcting that. By setting *count = 1* this extra line can be left out.

Comment: @Rexy I went through different versions of this code now and I can't seem to reproduce that error. Copy the code that's in my post now, it works for me.

Comment: A bit iffy with `printf(text);` as `text`, in general, may contain `"%"`.  Consider `printf("%s", text);` or the like.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly you do not know how to implement a corresponding function.

It can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * replace_pluses( char *s )
{
    const char plus = '+';
    const char odd_plus = 'p';
    const char even_plus = 'P';

    char *dsn = s;

    for ( char *src = s; *src;  )
    {
        if ( *src == plus )
        {
            int odd = 1;
            while ( *++src == plus ) odd ^= 1;

            *dsn++ = odd ? odd_plus : even_plus;
        }
        else
        {
            if ( dsn != src ) *dsn = *src;
            ++dsn;
            ++src;

        }
    }

    *dsn = '\0';

    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "kjlz++zux+++";

    puts( s );
    puts( replace_pluses( s ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
kjlz++zux+++
kjlzPzuxp
```

Or you can write a more generic function like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * replace_odd_even_duplicates( char *s, char c1, char c2, char c3 )
{
    char *dsn = s;

    for ( char *src = s; *src;  )
    {
        if ( *src == c1 )
        {
            int odd = 1;
            while ( *++src == c1 ) odd ^= 1;

            *dsn++ = odd ? c2 : c3;
        }
        else
        {
            if ( dsn != src ) *dsn = *src;
            ++dsn;
            ++src;

        }
    }

    *dsn = '\0';

    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "kjlz++zux+++";

    puts( s );
    puts( replace_odd_even_duplicates( s, '+', 'p', 'P' ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Rexy You wrote that either odd or even numbers. See the output of the demonstrative programs.

Comment: Any particular reason for `if ( dsn != src ) *dsn = *src;` versus just `*dsn = *src;`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica There is no access to memory so the code can be more  efficient. For example the pointers themselves can be stored in registers.